# Creating clojure atoms with a function

Tags: clojure

I want to 1) create a list of symbols with the function below; then 2) create atoms with these symbols/names so that the atoms can be modified from other functions. This is the function to generate symbols/names:

```
(defn genVars [ dist ]
    (let [ nms (map str (range dist)) neigs (map #(apply str "neig" %) nms) ]
        (doseq [ v neigs ]
            (intern *ns* (symbol v) [ ] )) 
     ))
```

If dist=3, then 3 symbols, neig0, ... neig2 are created each bound with an empty vector. If it is possible to functionally create atoms with these symbols so that they are accessible from other functions. Any help is much appreciated, even if there are other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: But what's the actual problem with your function? you generate symbols in current namespace, so you just need to wrap your vector with the `atom` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desire to generate names suggests you would be better served by a single map instead:

```
(def neighbours (atom (make-neighbours)))
```

Where the definition of `make-neigbours` might look something like this:

```
(defn make-neighbours []
  (into {} (for [i (range 10)]
             [(str "neig" i) {:age i}])))
```

Where the other namespace would look values up using something like:

```
(get-in @data/neighbours ["neig0" :age])
```

Idiomatic Clojure tends to avoid creating many named global vars, preferring instead to collocating state into one or a few vars governed by Clojure's concurrency primitives (atom/ref/agent). I encourage you to think about whether your problem can be solved with a single atom in this way instead of requiring defining multiple vars.

Having said that, if you really really need multiple atoms, consider storing them all in a single map var instead of creating many global vars. Personally, I have never encountered a situation where creating many atoms was better than a single big atom (so I would be interested to hear about situations where this would be important).

If you really really need many vars, be aware that defining vars inside a function is actually bad style (https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#dont-def-vars-inside-fns). With good reason too! The beauty of using functions and data comes from the purity of the functions. `def` inside a function is particularly nasty as it is not only a side-effect, but is an potentially execution flow altering side-effect.

Of course yes there is a way to achieve it, as another answer points out.

Where it comes to defining things that goes beyond `def` and `defn`, there is quite a lot of precedence to using macros. For example `defroutes` from compojure, `defschema` from Schema, `deftest` from clojure.test. Generally anything that is a convenience form for creating vars. You could use a macro solution to create defs for your atoms:

```
(defmacro defneighbours [n]
`(do
  ~@(for [sym (for [i (range n)]
              (symbol (str "neig" i)))]
    `(def ~sym (atom {}))))
```

In my opinion this is actually less offensive than a functional version, only because it is creating global defs. It is a little more obvious about creating global defs by using the regular `def` syntax. But I only bring it up as a strawman, because this is still bad.

The reason functions and data work best is because they compose.

There are tangible considerations that make a single atom governing state very convenient. You can iterate over all neighbors conveniently, you can add new ones dynamically. Also you can do things like concatenating neighbors with other neighbors etc. Basically there are lots of function/data abstractions that you lock yourself out of if you create many global vars.

This is the reason that macros are generally considered useful for syntactic tricks, but best avoided in favor of functions and data. And it has a real impact on the flexibility of your code. For example going back to compojure; the macro syntax is actually very limiting, and for that reason I prefer not to use `defroutes` at all.

In summary:

1. Don't make lots of global defs if you can avoid it.
2. Prefer 1 atom over many atoms where possible.
3. Don't def inside a function.
4. Macros are best avoided in favor of functions and data.
5. Regardless of these guidelines, it is always good to explore what is possible, and I can't know your circumstances, so above all I hope you overcome your immediate problem and find Clojure a pleasant language to use.

Comment: no need for this to be a macro, it can just be a function.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you for your answers. I believe either will be suitable. Is there a variation on the vector of atoms so that I could refer to the atoms by a name, like in the first solution, rather than by an index into a vector?

Comment: If you use a map instead of a vector, you can look up by name:  `(def atoms (into {} (for [n names] [n (atom {})])))`

Comment: general rule of thumb: never use a macro when a function will do. they are much more useful constructs than macros.

Comment: When it comes to anything that wraps up the behavior of `def`, I claim that a function is worse than a macro. I have elaborated my answer with why. Ultimately it is better to neither use a macro, nor a function, but just define the data as a single map inside an atom. The macro was really a strawman in that I do NOT recommend it, but was trying to answer the question as stated. Thanks for the comments pointing out that the answer was actually not expressing that, I certainly agree with your statements, but wanted to express more clearly why interning many symbols is something to be wary of.

Comment: Thank you Timothy for your explanation. I have taken your advice to heart and a solved my problem with 1 map atom. The code has become much cleaner and succinct. I am pleased with the above solutions as they might be useful at some point.

Answer (score 2):

your function seems to be correct, just wrap the value in the `intern` call with `atom` call. Also I would rather use `dotimes`.

```
user> 
(defn gen-atoms [amount prefix]
  (dotimes [i amount]
    (intern *ns* (symbol (str prefix i)) (atom []))))
#'user/gen-atoms
user> (gen-atoms 2 "x")
nil
user> x0
#atom[[] 0x30f1a7b]
user> x1
#atom[[] 0x2149efef]
```